# Android ListView - ExpandableHeightListView add a limit of 10 records per page

Tags: android-listview, android-adapter, pull-to-refresh, android-adapterview

My listview is found inside a `ScrollView`. The `ListView` was extended by `ExpandableHeightListView` class. When, 20 row items are loaded, the image library freeze the UI until all images are loaded. Then, user can scroll and select an item. To handle this issue, I tried to load every 10 records in the arraylist. Can i do it directly in the `ExpandableHeightListView` , if so how ?

```
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (isExpanded()) {

            //  int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

            //super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            //int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            //super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);


            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();

        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

The `ListView` adapter is as follows:

```
public class ResultatRechercheAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    public static final String IMAGE_CACHE_DIR = "images";
    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "extra_image";

    public List<MRechercheResult> items;
    public final OnClickListener itemButtonClickListener;
    public final Context context;
    public Activity activity;
    public String agenda_date;
    public String agenda_from;
    public String agenda_to;
    public ViewHolder holder;
    public int agenda_from_hour=-1;
    public int agenda_from_minute=-1;
    public int agenda_to_hour;
    public int agenda_to_minute;
    public String from_am_pm;
    public String to_am_pm;
    private String monday;
    private String tuesday;
    private String wednesday;
    private String thursday;
    private String friday;
    private String saturday;
    private String sunday;
    public ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;

    public ResultatRechercheAdapter(Activity activity,Context context, List<MRechercheResult> resultat, OnClickListener itemButtonClickListener) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = resultat;
        this.itemButtonClickListener = itemButtonClickListener;
        //this.mImageFetcher = mImageFetcher;

        try {

            monday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.monday);
            tuesday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.tuesday);
            wednesday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.wednesday);
            thursday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.thursday);
            friday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.friday);
            saturday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.saturday);
            sunday= activity.getResources().getString(R.string.sunday);

        } catch(Exception ex){}

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();//items.size()
    }

    @Override
    public MRechercheResult getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;//items.size()

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txRowTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txRowTitle);
            holder.imThumbnail= (RecyclingImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imThumbnail);
            holder.itemButton1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_card_close);
            holder.itemButton2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_card_button_2);

            holder.imCircleLundi= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleLundi);
            holder.imCircleMardi= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleMardi);
            holder.imCircleMercredi= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleMercredi);
            holder.imCircleJeudi= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleJeudi);
            holder.imCircleVendredi= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleVendredi);
            holder.imCircleSamedi= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleSamedi);
            holder.imCircleDimanche= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imCircleDimanche);

            holder.rlListRecherche= (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlListRecherche);
            holder.llImage= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llImage);
            holder.rlListClose= (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlListClose);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        boolean no_record  = items.get(position).no_record;

        if (no_record){ // listview is empty

            holder.llImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rlListClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rlListRecherche.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else { 


            Utils.shortWeek(activity, convertView);

            holder.llImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rlListClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rlListRecherche.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (itemButtonClickListener != null) {
                //holder.itemButton1.setOnClickListener(itemButtonClickListener);
                holder.itemButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.itemButton2.setOnClickListener(itemButtonClickListener);
            }

            final String image_url = items.get(position).profil_photo.toString().replace("\\","").replace("hepigo", "helpigo");
            String item_title = items.get(position).profil.toString();

            if (item_title.equalsIgnoreCase("Julien Perez")){

                if (true){
                    String display_pos = String.valueOf(position);
                    System.out.println(display_pos);
                }
            }

            //searchRequest(position,image_url);    

            //if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(image_url))
            //  mImageFetcher.loadImage(image_url, holder.imThumbnail);

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(items.get(position).profil_photo)) {
                        //no url 

                    } else {


                        Picasso.with(activity)
                        .load(image_url)
                        .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
                        .transform(transformation)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image_placeholder)
                        .config(Config.RGB_565)
                        .into(holder.imThumbnail);


                    }

                }
            });
            //if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(image_url))
            //  new DownloadImageTask(holder.imThumbnail).execute(image_url);

            holder.txRowTitle.setText(item_title);



            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    List<Agenda> agenda =  items.get(position).agenda;

                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleLundi,monday);
                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleMardi,tuesday);
                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleMercredi,wednesday);
                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleJeudi,thursday);
                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleVendredi,friday);
                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleSamedi,saturday);
                    Utils.displayAgenda(agenda,holder.imCircleDimanche,sunday);
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public RelativeLayout rlListClose;
        public LinearLayout llImage;
        public RelativeLayout rlListRecherche;
        public ImageView imCircleSamedi;
        public ImageView imCircleDimanche;
        public ImageView imCircleVendredi;
        public ImageView imCircleJeudi;
        public ImageView imCircleMercredi;
        public ImageView imCircleMardi;
        public ImageView imCircleLundi;
        public RecyclingImageView imThumbnail;

        public TextView txRowTitle;
        public Button itemButton1;
        public Button itemButton2;

    }
```